# ElectronNet.CLI recognize version as 2.2 even though my version is 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, electron, asp.net-core-2.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQNv.jpg

I had working with version 2.1 SDK at .net core, for installing electronNet.CLI, but for some reason I had error that the version is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2.
How to fix it?In which version is recommended to working with electronNet?

Comment: The screen shot is gone. Why cannot you edit the question and paste the complete error message?

Comment: Sorry about that - I fixed it.